# D3D11.2 Tiled Resources Tier support in AMD Radeon

Tags: directx, gpu, direct3d, amd-processor, direct3d11

I develop an application utilizing D3D11.2 Tiled Resources feature. I have GeForce 780 and some Radeon 7900 series graphics cards, but both support only Tier 1 set.

A year ago, AMD claimed to have a hardware fully supporting Tiled Resources, but Direct3D caps reporting, that only Tier 1 can be used, determined that was a lie (probably they had some issues with conformance, performance or stability and decided to release driver with Tier 2 disabled).

I found some links to articles, that there is a chance, that Tier 2 is supported in the recently released graphics cards, like for example:

> The different tier's represent the level of Tiled Resources feature supported under DX 11.2. R7 260X, R9 290 and R9 290X will have the ability to support the entire feature set, both tiers of Tiled Resources under DX 11.2 in Windows 8.1

Source: http://www.hardocp.com/article/2013/10/23/amd_radeon_r9_290x_video_card_review#.U_2OPflByjk

But IT journalist have usually no idea what they are writing about, especially when graphics hardware is concerned, so I'm asking the question here.

Is there any Radeon R7/R9 owner, who can confirm, that Tiled Resources Tier 2 is supported in these graphics cards?

Windows 8.1 SDK has tool called dxcapsviewer. You can check this in DXGI Devices -> (graphics card name) -> Direct3D 11.2 -> D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1 -> Tiled Resources.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R9 290 does indicate support for Tiled Resources Tier 2 in the caps viewer on the latest Catalyst beta driver.  It should also be enabled on the latest retail one as well.  The R7 should have the same level of support.

Comment: Just the R9 290/290X support it. I have an R9 280X and it doesn't !